# d3. plot subset of data with check box

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js, data-visualization, subset

I'm working on a visualization with some sample data where I would like to use a check box to select a subset of the data to plot.

Here is my current working example
http://bl.ocks.org/natemiller/76fed84e8d8c2f6632f6

Neither of the check boxes in the example are linked to any script yet, but what I would like is that when one or both of the boxes are checked a subset (or all) of the data (based on the column "temp") are available to be plotted.

I have tried looking through this example 
http://2011.12devsofxmas.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/datavis-final.html

but the extra "dirty data" code has confused me and I can't quite determine how to reference the check-boxes to subset the data. Can someone offer some pointers on how I might achieve what I imagine is pretty easy for more advance JS folks?